# Why wont my Servo Motor SG90 stop spinning?

Tags: automation, bluetooth, sensors, arduino-uno, servo

I am trying to control my servo motor using an LDR sensor. Operation should be like this,If there is no light detected then the servo motor should remain at 0 degrees, but if there is light then the servo motor should rotate 90 degrees and stop. As soon as the light if off, Is should return to its original position again.

```
#include<Servo.h>     //servo   
Servo my;              //servo

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600); 
 my.attach(3);     //servo   

  analogRead(A4);             //new motor
  float motor = analogRead(A4); 
if (motor <= 200)  //Light detected             
 {
  my.write(0);          //servo remains stationary

  }
 else
 {
  my.write(90); //open the gate 90degrees
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything after my.attach(3) should be in the main loop, not setup